# WPF always runs as en-US

Tags: wpf, localization

I've created a WPF app and run locbaml to create satellite assemblies.

This all works fine when I run the app and "hack" the UICulture from App.xaml.cs. However when running normally and changing the culture on my machine I see no differences. A little logging reveals the UICulture is always en-US.

I'm not sure why it isn't picking up the changes to regional settings I've made. I've changed every damn setting to Spanish but it's still not working!

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culture depends on the Windows version you have installed. If you installed the US version of Windows then your culture will always be *en-US* unless you physically **HACK** everything. This means you have to change the cultures on the Threads and possibly UIElements by using xml:lang

#### Examples:

Set the Threads culture:

```
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
```

Add en-US to supported Culture list in the csproj file (open with Notepad)

```
<SupportedCultures>en-US;</SupportedCultures>
```

Make sure every string (UIElement) has the correct culture

```
xml:lang="en-US"
```

Comment: Ah I see! I thought you'd be able to change regional settings and a different culture would apply. So there is no way to test this outside of hardcoding the settings and re-running the app. I wonder if it is easy to swap at runtime?

Comment: @user630190 there is no way to switch local at runtime using "locbaml approach"

Answer (score 0):

My advice is: do not use "locbaml" localization approach in WPF use "resx approach" instead. When we was developing our app, we used locbaml, but found it difficult to support, so we switched to resx and it becomes much more easier. As for changing language in runtime - AFAIK there is no way to implement this by using "locbaml approach".

You can find some localization extensions, like:

Light version: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30035/Simple-WPF-Localization

Full version: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35159/WPF-Localization-Using-RESX-Files
Full version can switch language in runtime.